# Почему переменная в первом классе меняется ,а во втором нет.хотя создал экземпляр первого класса во втором

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

```
public class Monet2 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject moneta;
    public GameObject trigger;
    public int score = 0;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            score = ++score;
        }
    }
}

public class End_round : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public int xyz = 0; 
    public int x = 0; 
    public int y = 0; 
    public int z = 0; 

    void1 Update()
    {
        Monet g = new Monet();
        Monet1 g1 = new Monet1(); 
        Monet2 g2 = new Monet2(); 
        Debug.Log(g.score); 
        Debug.Log(g1.score); 
        Debug.Log(g2.score); 
        xyz = x + y + z; 
        Debug.Log(xyz);
        if (xyz==3)
        { 
            Debug.Log("you win");
        }
    }
}
```

почему в первом классе меняется переменная "score" с нуля на единицу.А во втором классе она не меняется,а по идее должна.
заранее спасибо

Comment: В какой момент она должна меняться во втором классе?

Comment: Потому что у вас все совсем не так. Во первых почитайте какие предупреждения вам выдает. Там точно будет три предупреждения что нельзя использовать конструктор с monoBehaviour классом. Второе, у вас во втором классе нету никаких изменений переменной score . И к тому же не совсем понятно зачем вам три разных класса монеток. Чувствую что логика у них одна и та же.

Comment: получается что просто g.score должна меняться в каждом фрейме.то есть если score =0 то она принимает значение 0 если 1 то 1

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: выдает такую:you are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the new keyword.Monobehaviours can only added using AddComponent(); и т д

Comment: Подскажите что эта ошибка означает и как ее можно исправить

Comment: Проблема как раз в том где вы пишите Money money = new Money()  Так нельзя делать. Вам нужно брать ссылки на эти объекты с gameObject на котором они висят

Comment: Если у вас будут ссылки на них тогда вы сможете видеть изменения score

Comment: Сейчас оформлю вам ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не видите изменений  score  потому что у вас нету ссылки на объект который  его хранит.
Не рекомендуется использовать конструктор с классами которые наследуют MonoBehaviour. 
Что бы получить ссылку на него вам нужно

```
public Money money;
```

и в инспекторе перетащить объект на котором висит этот скрип. Теперь в вашей переменной money  будет ссылка на нужный объект и вы будете видеть изменения.
 Еще ссылку можно получить используя

```
Money money = someObjectWithAttachedMoneyClass.GetComponent<Money>();
```

Comment: я новичок в unity не могли бы вы поподробнее обьяснить как длается первый способ и как второй

Comment: Вот смотрите. Объявляете публичную переменную типа Money  Сохраняете скрипт. Ждёте пока юнити все скомпилируйте. Смотрите на объект на котором висит этот скрипт. В инспекторе в нем должно появиться поле в которое можно перенести другой объект на котором висит класс Money

Comment: Второй способ почти аналогичный. Только вы передаёте не сам класс Money а gameObject на котором он висит. И далее так как я описывал.

Comment: обьвлять публичную переменную в классе 1 или во 2

Comment: http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=42041

Comment: Во втором. Я ссылку скинул где это хорошо показано.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html

Comment: А вот ещё. Там более точно и глубоко.

Comment: я перетащил обьект что делать дальше

Comment: andrey я перетащил обьект что делать дальше пожалуйста подскажите

Comment: Теперь у вас есть ссылка на него. И теперь вы будете видеть изменения значения score

Comment: спасибо огромное вам сейчас попробую докодить если что отпишусь вам

Comment: а с этой ссылкой надо что то делать и можно ли заменить это-Monet g = new Monet();на это-Monet g =gameObject.AddComponent<Monet>();

Comment: вы можете так сделать. Но это будет уе совсем другая ссылка, а не та что вы передали как писали раньше . И соответственно score  будет другой

Comment: не совсем понял

Comment: у вас уже есть ссылка на класс монеты. А таким вот способом вы добавите класс монеты к gameObject  на котором висит скрипт где вы это прописываете. Соответственно это две совсем разные ссылки и score  будет для них разный.

Comment: то есть вот это уже не нужно(Monet g =gameObject.AddComponent<Monet>();)

Comment: в данном случае нет. Разве что вы хотите добавить еще одну Монету

Comment: спасибо огромное еще раз)